# The redirected constructor has incompatible parameters

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using `builtvalue` in my project
I have a `json` that looks as follows

```
{ "status": 1, "msg": "Success", "data": [ { "feeID": "25", "collectionID": "0", "type": 1, "category": "3 Fee", "schemeInfo": { "schemeID": 0, "schemeNo": 0, "schemeTxt": "", "schemeStatus": 1 }, "feeCode": "ISter Fee", "feeShortName": "", "basicAMT": "120000", "scholarshipInfo": { "scholarship": "0", "scholarshipAMT": 0, "scholarshipIDs": [] }, "dueDate": "2018-05-10", "lateFeeInfo": { "lateFeePerDay": "0", "lateDays": 28, "lateFeeAMT": 0 }, "taxInfo": { "tax": "18", "taxAMT": 21600, "taxAddedAMT": 141600 }, "grandAMT": 141600, "status": "2", "dateStatus": "1", "collectionDetailStatus": -1 }, { "feeID": "54", "collectionID": "0", "type": 1, "category": "4th Semester Tuition Fee", "schemeInfo": { "schemeID": 0, "schemeNo": 0, "schemeTxt": "", "schemeStatus": 1 }, "feeCode": "ISion Fee", "feeShortName": "", "basicAMT": "120000", "scholarshipInfo": { "scholarship": "0", "scholarshipAMT": 0, "scholarshipIDs": [] }, "dueDate": "2018-10-30", "lateFeeInfo": { "lateFeePerDay": "0", "lateDays": 28, "lateFeeAMT": 0 }, "taxInfo": { "tax": "18", "taxAMT": 21600, "taxAddedAMT": 141600 }, "grandAMT": 141600, "status": "2", "dateStatus": "1", "collectionDetailStatus": -1 } ], "wallet": { "walletID": "1483", "walletNo": "", "NTB": "25000.00", "WAB": "0.00", "status": "empty" } }
```

Following is my model class using `builtvalue`

```
library fee_model;

import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';

part 'fee_model.g.dart';

abstract class FeeModel implements Built<FeeModel,FeeModelBuilder> {
FeeModel._();

factory FeeModel([updates(FeeModelBuilder b)]) = _$FeeModel;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'status')
int get status;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'msg')
String get msg;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'data')
BuiltList get data;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'wallet')
Wallet get wallet;

static Serializer get serializer => _$feeModelSerializer;

}

abstract class FeeData implements Built<FeeData, FeeDataBuilder> {
FeeData._();

factory FeeData([updates(FeeDataBuilder b)]) = _$FeeData;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'feeID')
String get feeID;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'collectionID')
String get collectionID;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'type')
int get type;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'schemeInfo')
SchemeInfo get schemeInfo;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'category')
String get category;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'feeCode')
String get feeCode;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'feeShortName')
String get feeShortName;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'basicAMT')
String get basicAMT;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'scholarshipInfo')
ScholarshipInfo get scholarshipInfo;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'dueDate')
String get dueDate;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'lateFeeInfo')
LateFeeInfo get lateFeeInfo;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'taxInfo')
TaxInfo get taxInfo;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'grandAMT')
double get grandAMT;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'status')
String get status;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'dateStatus')
String get dateStatus;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'collectionDetailStatus')
int get collectionDetailStatus;

static Serializer get serializer => _$feeDataSerializer;

}

abstract class Wallet implements Built<Wallet,WalletBuilder> {
Wallet._();

factory Wallet([updates(WalletBuilder wb)]) = _$Wallet;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'walletID')
String get walletID;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'walletNo')
String get walletNo;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'NTB')
String get nTB;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'WAB')
String get wAB;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'status')
String get status;

static Serializer get serializer => _$walletSerializer;

}

abstract class SchemeInfo implements Built<SchemeInfo,SchemeInfoBuilder>{
SchemeInfo._();

factory SchemeInfo([updates(SchemeInfo si)]) = _$SchemeInfo;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'schemeID')
int get schemeID;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'schemeNo')
int get schemeNo;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'schemeTxt')
String get schemeTxt;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'schemeStatus')
int get schemeStatus;

static Serializer get serializer =>
_$schemeInfoSerializer;
}

abstract class ScholarshipInfo implements Built<ScholarshipInfo,ScholarshipInfoBuilder> {
ScholarshipInfo._();

factory ScholarshipInfo([updates(ScholarshipInfo si)]) = _$ScholarshipInfo;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'scholarship')
String get scholarship;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'scholarshipAMT')
int get scholarshipAMT;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'scholarshipIDs')
BuiltList get scholarshipIDs;

static Serializer get serializer => _$scholarshipInfoSerializer;
}

abstract class LateFeeInfo implements Built<LateFeeInfo, LateFeeInfoBuilder>{
LateFeeInfo._();

factory LateFeeInfo([updates(LateFeeInfo lfi)]) = _$LateFeeInfo;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'lateFeePerDay')
String get lateFeePerDay;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'lateDays')
int get lateDays;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'lateFeeAMT')
int get lateFeeAMT;

static Serializer get serializer => _$lateFeeInfoSerializer;
}

abstract class TaxInfo implements Built<TaxInfo,TaxInfoBuilder>{
TaxInfo._();

factory TaxInfo([updates(TaxInfo ti)]) = _$TaxInfo;

@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'tax')
String get tax;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'taxAMT')
double get taxAMT;
@nullable
@BuiltValueField(wireName: 'taxAddedAMT')
double get taxAddedAMT;

static Serializer get serializer => _$taxInfoSerializer;

}
```

I ran the command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build` then too i get error saying `redirected construcot has incompatible parameters`

I have attached a screenshot

[image]

I keep getting the error at `SchemeInfo,ScholarshipInfo,LateFeeInfo,TaxInfo` but not at `Wallet,FeeData,FeeModel` class
I am not sure whether this a bug in the `builtvalue` library itself or am i doing something wrong as i have created other model class in my project as well and they run fine without the above error mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says

```
factory SchemeInfo([updates(SchemeInfo si)]) = _$SchemeInfo;
```

should be

```
factory SchemeInfo([updates(SchemeInfoBuilder si)]) = _$SchemeInfo;
```